# Cast from renamed type in google go

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm trying to write suitable method of converting appengine/datastore.Time type to string.
This type is declared as `type Time int64`
But when i'm trying to use it as int64 value:

```
localTime := time.SecondsToLocalTime(t/1000)
```

I'm receiving error message

> cannot use t / 1000 (type
>   datastore.Time) as type int64 in
>   function argument

Assignment from int64 to Time typed variable is successfull, but how can i cast it back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do it like

```
time.SecondsToLocalTime(int64(t)/1000)
```

See more in the documentation about [Conversions](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Conversions)